# Recover Data from Encrypted LUKS HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, luks

Hei, I really need help with this!

Yesterday my Kubutnu wouldnt boot anymore so I booted with a Live CD and could fix the problem with this Tutorial: http://www.citizen428.net/blog/2011/10/17/fixing-grub-on-a-luks-encrypted-disk

The problem appeared again after every reboot and now this tutorial won't work anymore.

I tried to mount the LUKS partiton like this:

```
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 LUKS
```

then I get the error that sda3 is not a valid LUKS device.

So I tried several things:

"parted -l" gives me this output:

```
root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LM014-SSHD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB               EFI System Partition  msftdata
 2      538MB   794MB   256MB  ext2
 3      794MB   1000GB  999GB
```

"fdisk -l /dev/sda" gives this one:

```
root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# fdisk -l /dev/sda

    WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk         doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Then I tried "smartctl -a /dev/sda" and got this output:

```
root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.2-64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Laptop SSHD
Device Model:     ST1000LM014-SSHD-8GB
Serial Number:    W381F3FN
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 073553aa5
Firmware Version: LVD3
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Dec 18 10:52:25 2014 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  161) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 196) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   114   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       62542976
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   098   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1136
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   070   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       17224568354
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1279
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1177
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       131078
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   051   046   045    Old_age   Always       -       49 (Min/Max 38/51)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       324
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       5294
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   049   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       49 (0 17 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 441 hours (18 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 71 03 80 04 11 40

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      01:11:21.443  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  61 00 08 e8 7d 66 40 00      01:11:21.443  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 d0 d8 c9 66 40 00      01:11:21.443  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 80 38 9f 49 44 00      01:11:21.279  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00      01:11:21.278  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I'm running "badblocks -v /dev/sda" and TestDisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is Scanning the HDD for partitions but that takes a very long time.

Thank you for reading! I hope there is a way to at least temp fix this so I can get the backups of my data.

Comment: From my understanding, the general advice for encrypted devices is to backup the headers, because without these, recovery is amlost impossible if the datastructure becomes corrupt.

Comment: In general, recovering an encrypted disk is almost impossible --- you can't easily distinguish between a failure and an attempt to break the encryption, so basically it's a feature. This is the reason redundant backups are even more important if you use an encrypted disk.